# Right continuity of mean value function from a submartingale

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes

This may be a stupid question but: Let $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq}$ be a submartingale and  define $$m_X(t+):=\lim_{s\downarrow t} E[X_s]$$ and assume it exists (I know it always does).
Why is then $t \mapsto m_X(t+)$ right-continuous? Is it a tautology?

Edit (as respond to edit): The double downarrow was intended, is it not usual notation for convergence strictly from above?

Comment: It would be better anyway to write $s\to t+0$. I've usually seen $s\downarrow t$ as an alternative to this, but I am not familiar with $s\downarrow \downarrow t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a submartingale we know that $t \mapsto \mathbb{E}(X_t)$ is increasing. Hence

$$m_X(t+) = \inf_{s>t} \mathbb{E}(X_s)$$

Now let $t \geq 0$ and $(t_n)_n$ a sequence such that $t_n \downarrow t$. Then $m_X(t_n+)$ is decreasing (in $n$) and therfore

$$m_X(t+) = \inf_{s>t} \mathbb{E}(X_s) = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} m_X(t_n+) = \lim_{n \to \infty} m_X(t_n+)$$